# Cytoscape JS - Modifying Container Height After Initialization

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I initialize Cytoscape with something that looks like the following:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: $('#my-element'),
    height: 500px
});
```

I would like to change the height of the container element to something other than the original `500px` value when an user commits an action.

How would I do this with Cytoscape?  There is a `height()` method in the main Cytoscape object, but this only functions as a getter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a documented method `cy.resize()` that you can call to redraw the graph to fit within the context of the current container's height / width.  You won't however get the desired results just by calling this method.  You'll also have to call the `cy.fit()` function afterwards to get the new graph view you want.

So your function to resize the container should look something like this:

```
function resizeContainer(newContainerHeight){
    $('#my-element').css('height', newContainerHeight);
    cy.resize();
    cy.fit();
}
```