# Assiging a cytoscape div height as the remaining of the parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, cytoscape.js

I am using cityscape to render a graph in a div. My HTML is as follows

```
<div class='container'>
<div id='inputContainer'></div>
<div id='cy'></div> 
</div>
```

The cytoscape graph is rendered under the div with id as 'cy'. Now, when I shrink the container div, the cityscape graph overflows out of the container div. Following is my css

```
#inputContainer {
        height: 20%;
    }

    #cy {
        position: absolute;
        height: 75%;
        width: 97%;
        z-index: 999;
        align-content: center;
    }
```

I tried the flex method to assign th cy div, remaining height

```
#cy {
        position: absolute;
        width: 97%;
        z-index: 999;
        flex: 1;
    }

    #inputContainer {
        height: 20%;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

With this, the graph is not being rendered. I noticed that the height of the graph's div is 0px. The calc method also doesn't seem to work. Could you please help me how to basically make the div with id 'cy', take the height as the remaining height in the parent div with class 'container'. Is there a way where when the resize event is triggered, I compute the height of the #inputContainer div and assign the height to the #cy div as : (height of .container div) - (height of #inputContainer div) ?

Comment: If #cy is in absolute position, it is not part of the flow of it's parent anymore , it is not acting as a flex child anymore Also, .container would require an height , height:20% for #inputContainer has ameaning and can be calculated.

Comment: @G-Cyr, thanks for the reply. I did add the height property to the .container. I still see a tiny bit of overflow when I shrink the div. Also, the cytoscape framework seems to have an issue, due to which the graph is being rendered only when I set the div's position as absolute or fixed. Would using fixed position help with the flex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cytoscape JS - Modifying Container Height After Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194851/cytoscape-js-modifying-container-height-after-initialization)

Comment: Hey @StephanT., so when div or window resizes, I am doing a cy.resize() and cy.fit(). But here in my case, the #inputContainer div is non-responsive. So I want the #cy div to take up the remaining space when a div is resized. Thats the reason why I am trying a flex approach. Currently, my #cy div fits inside the parent .container div, but it overlaps with the #inputContainer div, even though Ive given it a height of 20%

Comment: Cytoscape is not responsive, changes to the parent element after initialization won't do anything, as I said. You will have to listen to the height changes of the parent element and resize the cy element according to that. The approach of having a spacing component is ok i guess, but you also could just use the cytoscape component as the container and set the height there?